# How to transfer and show Smiley in between Android or iOS and Web (HTML)

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm facing problem to show Smiley on html content where text is generated from Android or iPhone keyboard and stored in MySQL database. Right now I'm storing smiley as unicode text in database so it is converting like \ud83d\ude01 . But there is no way to show this kind of encoded smiley in html.

I understand that not all smiley are supported in HTML code, but I want to show as much as possible like "☺" is supported so it should show, and for unsupported html smiley, "񏥠" kind of text is fine.

Comment: `\ud83d\ude01` is Unicode codepoints, not UTF-8.  What process generated that?

Comment: @RickJames Thanks. I update my query. That unicode is generated from client side (Android & iPhone).

Comment: Please state all the steps that the data goes through.  We need to find some application code that will translate the Unicode into UTF-8.

Comment: You should be able to use ☺ all the way through (with a MySQL field of utf8mb4). You shouldn't need to convert to any escaped UTF-16 computer programming language syntax.